# Unable to exclude directory from search in sublime

Tags: sublime-text-3

I wanted to exclude the `build` folder from sublime search.

I edited the project config file and added the `folder_exclude_patterns` line:

```
{

    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": "./build/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I search I did getting hit like this:

[image]

What did I do wrong?